# location.load() is not working in iphone browers

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

location.reload() is working fine on desktop browsers but not working on browser of IPhone.

Is there any alternative function to this in Jquery mobile.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location = window.location;
```